# solving systems of equations in terms of a,b,c

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given:

$$5x+3y+z=2 \\
  6x+5y+4z=8$$

if a,b,c is a solution then what is a+b+c? This is a problem from a math competition. Even if you let x=a, y=b, z=c, You cannot possibly come up with a value because there is a free variable which can take on any value. This problem makes no sense.

Then there is an another question $$x^2+15xy=x+15y \\
                                    y^2-xy=15x+y$$

Which asks how many solutions does the system have?

George runs from home to school at 9mph, then jogs at 4.5mph from school to the store. Then bikes back home. The average speed was 7.5 mph. Also all routes are equidistant. Find how fast he biked home.

$$\frac{4.5+9+x}{3} = 7.5$$ From here I get an answer of 9 but that is not correct.

Comment: You should ask only one question per post.  I'll be easier to sort out the solution.

Comment: For your second problem, first equation could be rewritten $x(x+15y) = x+15y$, so either $x=1$ of $x+15y=0$

Answer (score 1):

The first system has the solutions $a=c - 2$ and $b=2( 2- c)$, so that
$$
a+b+c=c-2-2(c-2)+c=2-c+c=2.
$$
The second system has the solutions (by substitution, see the comment by Alain),
$$
(x,y)=(1,-\sqrt{15}), (1,\sqrt{15}),(0,0),(\frac{1695}{8},-\frac{113}{8}).
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$5x+3y+z=2 \\
  6x+5y+4z=8$$

is equivalent to $$5x+3y=2-z \\
  6x+5y=4(2-z)$$

Let $ w= 2-z$ and solve the system in terms of $w$

We get $ x=-w$ , $y= 2w$, $z=w+2$

Therefore $$x+y+z=2$$

Answer (score 1):

> You cannot possibly come up with a value because there is a free variable which can take on any value. This problem makes no sense.

But the other two variables will take on values *based on that value* and the *sum* of the variables may be a constant even if the individual terms can not be known.

After all.  You know $5x + 3y + z=2$ always even though you don't know what $x,y,$ or $z$ are.

And you know that $6x + 5y + 4z =8$ always.  And if we subtract them we know

$x + 2y + 3z = 6$ even though we don't know what $x,y,z$ are.

SO can we figure out what

$x + y + z =k$ is?

Maybe.  Maybe not.

But the question *does* make sense.

Even if you have a free variable, say $x$, then you have $y = mx +d$ and $z=nx + e$.  And that means $x+y+z =x + mx + d + nx+e = (m+n+1)x + (d+e)$.

And that *will* have a solution if and only if $m+n+1= 0$

$5x+3y+z=2 \\
  6x+5y+4z=8$

If I solve this in any convenient way (I'll multiply the first equation by $4$ and subtract to get $14x + 7y=0$ and $y=-2x$ and I'll plug that into the first equation to get that $5x-6x+z=2$ or $z=x +2$)

We get $x=x; y=-2x; z=2+x$ and $x+y+z = x-2x+2+x =2$.

It could be $x =5$ and $y=-10$ and $z =12$ or it could be $x=y=0$ and $z = 2$.  We don't know.  But $x + y +z =2$ always.

.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

You can make a augemented matrix and do ref operations till you get form of  [1 1 1 | ...]